Error while calling Java overloaded method Path.of from Clojure
I'm new to Clojure and learning. I'm trying to create a java Path object in Clojure using Path.of() method, but when I call this
(import '(java.nio.file Path))
(Path/of "~/projects")

I get error
; Execution error (ClassCastException) at prog-clojure.2/eval10600 (form-init5937344406109919668.clj:34).
; class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.net.URI (java.lang.String and java.net.URI are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

When I saw javadoc for of method of java.nio.file.Path  it is overloaded method. with two methods being


static Path of(String first, String... more)



static Path of(URI uri)



I tried different ways of calling such as
(. Path of "~/projects")

but get same error.
Ideally it should return a Path object. How do I fix this?

The method static Path of(String first, String... more) is a vararg method. When such method is invoked in Java, an array is constructed and passed for the vararg argument. This is done implicitly by the compiler.
But in Clojure, you will have to explicitly pass the (potentially empty) array. You can construct one with into-array or make-array.
user=> (Path/of "~/projects" (into-array String []))
#object[sun.nio.fs.UnixPath 0xc9d82f9 "~/projects"]


Yes, your code is calling the single-argument arity of the function, which requires a URI as argument. To call one that takes a string as its first argument, you need to pass the second argument, which is an array of strings. In your case you want that argument to be empty. So, like this:
(java.nio.file.Path/of "~/Documents" (make-array String 0))
-> #object[sun.nio.fs.UnixPath 0x7447da74 "~/Documents"]


(Path/of (.toURI (io/file "~/")))

